# Знаки препинания при конструкции "каких поискать"

Tags: грамматика, грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая перед словами "каких поискать". Например: мастер, каких поискать - мастер каких поискать

Answer (score 5):

Я бы не ставила никаких знаков. Каких поискать - устойчивое сочетание. Мастер каких поискать - это  мастер отличный!

У Розенталя точно такого же случая не нашла, но очень похоже на другие сочетания с союзными словами.

*Цельные по смыслу выражения не выделяются знаками препинания.
1.      Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний, например: сделать как следует (как полагается, как подобает), выполнить как должно (как надо, как нужно), хватать что подвернется, явиться как ни в чем не бывало, говорить что в ум взбредёт, добиваться во что бы то ни стало, приходить когда вздумается, спрятаться кто куда успел, не лезть куда не следует, ночевать где придется, делай что хочешь, бери что нравится, спасайся кто может, есть что дают, будь что будет, идти куда глаза глядят, живите как знаете, приглашу к себе кого пожелаю, заплатил Бог знает сколько, кричит что есть мочи, рассказать все как есть, выдумывали кто во что горазд, достать что нужно (но: достать все, что нужно), черт знает что у них творится, городить черт знает что, поживиться чем можно, дать чего не жалко, картина чудо как хороша, страсть как интересно, ужас как трудно, беда как плохо.*

Answer (score 2):

Фразеологизмы имеют значение одного слова  и, как правило,   не обособляются, но это не значит, что они никогда не обособляются. (По аналогии одно слово  обычно не обособляется, но бывают случаи, когда его  можно обособить). Все зависит от структуры предложения, например: Люди шли как во сне – люди, как во сне, шли молча. Также: Мужики заснули как убитые. Наутро, как убитые, заснули мужики. Оборот «каких поискать» является устойчивым выражением, но при этом часто обособляется, например: «Зато он (такой) делец, каких поискать». В этом случае  мы имеем сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным определительным, указательное слово ТАКОЙ подразумевается. В то же время можно составить предложение, где оборот можно не обособлять, например: Мастер каких поискать, он брался за самую сложную работу. Но и здесь оборот может считаться уточняющим и обособляться. Поэтому вариант с обособлением встречается чаще, но это не повод для того, чтобы не считать оборот фразеологическим.

Answer (score 1):

Я не воспринимаю как фразеологизм, фраза легко меняется, в неё можно вставлять слова: Каких ещё поискать, каких нужно(надо)поискать, каких в нашем государстве поискать, каких у нас поискать и т.д. Посмотрела в Нац.корпусе, во всех худ.произведениях с запятой, вот, например, Е.Замятин, очень грамотный человек:   " Не речист, правда, Сазыкин и не первой уж молодости и чем-то на Емельяна Пугачева сдаёт― да зато делец, каких поискать". [Е. И. Замятин. Русь (1923)] 
http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA%E0%EA%E8%F5+%EF%EE%E8%F1%EA%E0%F2%FC

Comment: А в справочниках не видели именно этой фразы?

Comment: В справочниках и во фразеологическом словаре его нет,или мне не встречался.